# Using Python PyQT4 slots and signals in Monkey Studio

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm writing my first GUI application using PyQT4 and the Monkey Studio ide.

I've made a dialog (mainwindow.ui) with a button that sends the signal `clicked()` to the MainWindow's slot `slot1()`

This is the MainWindow code:

```
from PyQt4 import uic

(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow) = uic.loadUiType('mainwindow.ui')

class MainWindow (QMainWindow):
    """MainWindow inherits QMainWindow"""

    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def __del__ (self):
        self.ui = None

    def slot1(self):
        print "Test"
```

It does not work: `AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'slot1'`

I've tried adding `@pyqtSlot("")` before `def slot1(self)`, but I get this error:
    NameError: name 'pyqtSlot' is not defined

I've also tried `@QtCore.pyqtSignature("slot1()")`, to no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I also had to import `from PyQt4.QtCore import *`, which made me able to use `@pyqtSlot()`.

**Without** the quotes, because that would throw another C++ error.